# Переадресация домена .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

У меня есть домен и поддомен: [sub.test1.ru](http://sub.test1.ru) и [test1.ru](http://test1.ru), надо из них сделать мультисайтинг.Надо, когда я захожу на [sub.test1.ru](http://sub.test1.ru), чтобы меня перенаправило на [test1.ru](http://test1.ru), но url остался тот же... Как бы я зашел на поддомен и у меня открылся тот же сайт только с другим наполнением.

Answer (score 3):

Это делается не в .htaccess а в настройках apache

выставлением ServerAlias в Apache.

[ServerAlias Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).